# wooCommerce call function in checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function in my themes functions.php file which displays some information about the product.  On the checkout page below the billing address I want to out put the information there.

Here is my function in the themes functions.php

```
function wc_checkout_description_so_1( $other_data, $cart_item )
{
    $post_data = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );  
    echo '<div>HTML OUTPUT HERE</div>';

}
```

I have tried to use add_filter to below the billing address but doesnt not work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_shipping_form', 'wc_checkout_description_so_1', 10, 2 );
```

All I need is the output below the shipping information and the above I think should work?

Thanks

J

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form` might be more appropriate for displaying something after the shipping address. Either way, the only variable that is passed to the `woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form` hook is the `$checkout` variable. You can `var_dump` that variable to see what it is available.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form', 'wc_checkout_description_so_1' );
function wc_checkout_description_so_1( $checkout )
{
    var_dump( $checkout );

}
```